# What are the numbers in Tesseract box file?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I cannot for the love of me find any documentation about how Tesseract box files work, and what the coordinates represent.

For instance, I'm getting:

```
T 2768 165 2789 191 0
```

The first token is obviously the character. I know that Tesseract uses bottom-left. `2768` should therefore be the bottom. The 4th token (`2789`) seems to be the top. I don't get what the 3rd (`165`), 5th (`191`), and 6th (`0`) tokens are. `165` and `191` are incorrect as left/right coordinates, and `0` I have no idea what it refers to.

Can anyone help me? Are these pixel coordinates, or do I have to factor in the DPI of the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2018/07/09/training-tesseract-models-from-scratch), the format for each line is

```
<symbol> <left> <bottom> <right> <top> <page>
```

Where:

- `<symbol>` is the character e.g. a or b.
- `<left> <bottom> <right> <top>` are the coordinates of the rectangle that fits the character on the page. Note that the coordinates system used by Tesseract has (0,0) in the bottom-left corner of the image!
- `<page>` is only relevant if you’re using multi-page TIFF files. In all other cases just put 0 in here.

So in your particular case

```
T 2768 165 2789 191 0
```

would be

- character: `T`
- left: `2768`
- bottom: `165`
- right: `2789`
- top: `191`
- page: `0`

Comment: Ha! Thanks for linking the documentation! I guess the <bottom> and <left> coordinates are wrong, then. It's just a character, so if that's pixels or points the numbers should be very similar. I'll look at the docs to see if I can find out more. Thanks!!

Comment: how these numbers are calculated. How can i convert into cartesian coordinate ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked page is no longer available